# Custom shape in ggplot (geom_point)

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Aim**

I am trying to change the shape of the `geom_point` into a cross (so not a "plus/addition" sign, but a 'death' cross).

**Attempt**

Let say I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text="x y
                 1    3 
                 2    4 
                 3    6 
                 4    7 ", header=TRUE)
```

I am able to change the shape using the `shape` parameter in `geom_point` into different shapes, like this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x =x, y=y)) +  
   geom_point(shape=2)   # change shape
```

However, there is no option to change the shape into a cross.

**Question**

How do I change the shape of a value into a cross using ggplot in R?

Comment: Try `shape = 4`

Comment: you can refer http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape for all shapes available

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Shape can be set to a unicode character.  The below uses the skull and crossbones but you can look up a more suitable symbol.

Note that the final result will depend on the font used to generate the plot.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x =x, y=y)) +  
  geom_point(shape="\u2620", size = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: "\u2020" was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: [Here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/So) or [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/) is a list of other choices.